# How to remove automatic axis label stretching?

Tags: java, label, jfreechart, axis, scaling

I am using [`JFreeChart 1.0.14`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/1.%20JFreeChart/1.0.14/). The labels of my axis stretch really strangely if the plot is too small/big. I want to turn off that behaviour and want the axis labels always printed at the same width:height ratio.

[image: stretched]

Here is an SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("series a");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            series.add(i, Math.sin(i / 2.0) * Math.cos(i / (2.0 + Math.random())));
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "x-axis", "y-axis", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It produces the output marked with the `OK`. When I change the size of the frame in either direction to a certain amount, the axis labels (and tick labels) are starting to get distorted (as can be seen by the two frames marked with `stretched`). And their "stretching factor" is synced.

I can not figure out how to disable this "feature" and always display the the axis labels at a fixed width:height ratio. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an example of [scaling](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13401).

You need to set the maximum and minimum draw height and width on the `ChartPanel`.  You can either set them once:

```java
ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
panel.setMaximumDrawHeight(1000);
panel.setMaximumDrawWidth(1000);
panel.setMinimumDrawWidth(10);
panel.setMinimumDrawHeight(10);
```

using some suitable values or add a `ComponentListener`:

```java
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            panel.setMaximumDrawHeight(e.getComponent().getHeight());
            panel.setMaximumDrawWidth(e.getComponent().getWidth());
            panel.setMinimumDrawWidth(e.getComponent().getWidth());
            panel.setMinimumDrawHeight(e.getComponent().getHeight());
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you're using jFreeChart with SWT, those variables must be set when you instantiate a new `ChartComposite`.  There are no `set` methods for those variables on this class.